# DeleteFile with Permission Denied

Tags: vbscript, automation

I'm running into and issue that has many entries on Stack Overflow, but none of them solved my problem.

I have this piece of code, which tries to delete every .txt in a folder, but I keep getting a permission denied error on the "DeleteFile" command:

```
directory = "C:\TEST\FOLDER"

Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Function DeleteTXTs
        For Each f In fso.GetFolder(directory).Files
            If LCase(fso.GetExtensionName(f)) = "txt" Then
                fso.DeleteFile("C:\TEST\FOLDER\*.txt"),DeleteReadOnly
            End If
        Next
    End Function
```

My permissions on the "C:\TEST" and subfolders are of full control to every account that exists in windows... What could I do?

Comment: Your code is incomplete. Please provide a [short, self-contained example](http://sscce.org/), so that people could try to reproduce the problem. Also post the exact error message (including line and error number).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have tested the code and it works correctly, is it worth adding in `On Error Resume Next` error handling in the `For` loop, as it may be a specific file that is causing the problem. A second test would be have you declared the `DeleteReadOnly` correctly as when i removed this from the code i also received a "permission denied" when the code reached a read only .txt file. Finally if you have changed permissions on a folder have you done the old faithful reboot.

Comment: My DeleteReadOnly is set ae True... I forgot to paste it there.

Comment: Each of these was done... Still can't exclude the archives. I'm getting crazy with this issue...

Comment: How can I add a "On Error Resume Next" to my code? I also can't get OpenTextFile to work...

Comment: @ZeldaElf `On Error Resume Next` is VBScript's "shut up, I know what I'm doing" switch, so do **NOT** use it unless you actually *do* know what you're doing.

Comment: @Ansgar, I'm almost sure te problem is with my permissions. My account in under a windows domain and even though I'm the administrator, it seems that changin permissions inside this folder properties isn't enough... I'm afraid I'll need to delete files manually :(

Comment: for me I just needed to pass true to delete read only file as well